# How to implement Authentication with Facebook in API Gateway based on user property in DynamoDB?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have a mobile app which accesses some resources protected by API Gateway. Users will authenticate with Facebook and they will be able to access some resources but for other resources they will have to subscribe. What is the best way to implement this? Should I store a 'subscribed' flag in DynamoDB and use custom authorizers to somehow retrieve that flag and restrict access based on it? Provide examples, please.

Comment: I don't have any good examples to provide that are specific to your use case, but custom authorizer would work well for this. Or you can try Cognito User Pools which support custom scopes, which work well for this use case.

Comment: @JackKohn-AWS While this is true, it is very generic. I specifically need examples because it seems like a huge mystery to me how to use AWS services and achieve this without reinventing the wheel and writing tons of boilerplate